# Postcodes and distance MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

t_dealer contains dealer_name, dealer_state, dealer_postcode
t_postcodes contains p1, p2, dist
When looking up the distance, I always must make sure the lower (numerically) postcode is p1 and the higher one is p2 (unless they are equal).

Pre-Question: How can I make a join (or whatever else I need to do) that gives me the distance, given a customer surfs into the site and enters a postcode of (e.g.) 3000?

That's not too hard, I know - just do

```
if($postcode>$dealer_postcode){

  $query="select dist from t_postcodes where p1=$dealer_postcode and p2=$postcode limit 1";

} else {

  $query="select dist from t_postcodes where p2=$dealer_postcode and p1=$postcode limit 1";

}
```

Actual Question: I need to have all the dealers in the state (dealer_state) listed in a table (with jqgrid) which means I need 1 single query that pulls out all of the dealers and their respective distances from $postcode.

I have tried various joins and stuff but get nowhere even close.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: what country are the post codes from ?

Comment: Australia. SO the smallest is 800 and the highest is 7000 (or thereabouts)

Comment: I have found and tried `select dist,p1,p2,dealer_postcode from t_dealer, t_postcodes where (if(dealer_postcode<2000,p1,p2)=dealer_postcode) and (if(dealer_postcode<2000,p2,p1)=2000)` but it takes many minutes to run and uses 100% of the CPU in the meantime. 2000 would be the postcode that the client enters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the first part of the answer:

```
select dist,p1,p2,dealer_postcode from t_dealer, t_postcodes where (if(dealer_postcode<$user_postcode,p1,p2)=dealer_postcode) and (if(dealer_postcode<$user_postcode,p2,p1)=$user_postcode)
```

I got that mainly from [this](http://www.roseindia.net/mysql/mysql5/writing-subqueries.shtml) page (about sub queries).

The second part - the only thing to make it run without timing out or taking too long - is to limit the results. I initially had approx 2100 dealers. I limit it (by other criteria) down to 30 and then it runs OK

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar for another project (mind you it was ZipCodes) using the following article.  You could take the same principals and apply them to postal codes.

[ZipCode Radius Search Using MySQL](http://gabesumner.com/zip-code-radius-search-using-mysql)

Comment: Interesting, and may well be useful for the future, but for right now, the data structure and info is too different to make it work without starting from scratch.